# jQuery trigger event on multiple fields with the same classname

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple input fields that have the same class name, such as:

```
<input type="text" class="input-name" value="John">
<input type="text" class="input-name" value="Maria">
```

When someone presses `ENTER` in any field, the text `!!!` is automatically appended to the value. This works great.

```
$(document).on('keypress', '.input-name', function(event)
{
    if (event.which != 13)
       return;
    
   $(this).val($(this).val() + '!!!');
});
```

The problem is that I'd like to press a button and change the value of all fields, by simulating the `ENTER` keypress event and for some reason, it only triggers in the first input!

This only triggers in the first input:

```
var e = $.Event('keypress', { which: 13 });
$('.input-name').trigger(e);
```

This also only triggers in the first input:

```
$('.input-name').each(function(i, input)
{
   $(input).trigger(e);
});
```

You can see the problem in this **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jbchsopx/)**.

Comment: It's something to do with sharing the event amongst elements.  Move the event creation into the button click event handler, and it works.  EDIT: Sorry, move it into the `each` in the button click event handler so it is unique per element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define jquery `Event` object inside the `each` function callback as follows.

```
$('.input-name').each(function (i, input) {
  var e = $.Event('keypress', {
    which: 13
  });
  $(input).trigger(e);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just make a function that does the work and not deal with event handlers

```js
//function alterInps(inps) {
//  inps.val(function () { return this.value + "!!!"; });
//}

function alterInps(inps) {
  var re = /!!!$/;
  inps.val(function () { 
    return this.value + (re.test(this.value) ? '' : '!!!');
  });
}

$(document).on('keypress', '.input-name', function(event) {
  if (event.which != 13) return;
  alterInps($(this));
});

$('button').on("click", function () {
  alterInps($('.input-name'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input-name" value="John">
<input type="text" class="input-name" value="Maria">
<button type="buton">All</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.input-name').on('keypress', function(event)
{
    if (event.which != 13)
    return;
    
   $(this).val($(this).val() + '!!!');
});

$(document).on('click', '#btn-submit', function()
{
    var e = $.Event('keypress', { which: 13 });
    //$('.input-name').trigger(e);
  
  $('.input-name').each(function(i, input)
  {
    $(input).trigger(e);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn-submit">
  Click me
</button>

<input type="text" class="input-name" value="Maria">
<input type="text" class="input-name" value="John">
```